# Fill entire scene with buttons JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to work on a VBox, which I want to populate with up to 5 HBoxes containing up to 5 Buttons.
Also I need those buttons to be resizable but I can't get it done.
Already tried to use a static method returning an HBox, calling it from

```
primaryStage.getChildren.addAll(hBoxMethod());
```

Help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: please show us what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you try to do. But if your are trying to fill your sceen with 5x5 auto-resizing buttons (as the title sujects): Why not use a combination of GridPane and AnchorPanes for the resizing.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        AnchorPane rootPane = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 400, 300);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        MaximizeInAnchorPane(grid);

        // make column and rows resize
        for (int i=0;i <5;i++)
        {
            ColumnConstraints cConstrain = new ColumnConstraints();
            cConstrain.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cConstrain);

            RowConstraints rConstrain = new RowConstraints();
            rConstrain.setVgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(rConstrain);
        }

        for (int i=0;i <5;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j <5;j++)
            {
                // create button and put it in an AnchorPane, that will resize it
                AnchorPane buttonPane = new AnchorPane();
                Button button = new Button("Button");
                MaximizeInAnchorPane(button);
                buttonPane.getChildren().add(button);

                grid.add(buttonPane,i,j);
            }
        }

        rootPane.getChildren().add(grid);
        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void MaximizeInAnchorPane(Node toMaximize)
    {
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(toMaximize, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(toMaximize, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(toMaximize, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(toMaximize, 0.0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you are trying to resize everything manually you should take a look SplitPane. It all depends on what you want to resize how.

For me, it always helps playing around with JavaFX Scene Builder [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html) to figure out, how to do the layout I want.

Comment: Each button represents a product that a store offers, located in a database, which are categorized.
For example, the salesman chooses to sell Sodas, then the screen would be populated with all the soda the store have, like Coke, Sprite, etc.
The thing is that there will not always be 25 products, but I set it as a limit in case there are more than 25, which is not very probable unless they're not so well categorized.
Thank you for your answer, I'll try to manipulate de nested for, so that I add only the number of buttons desired.